# Ajax oncheck event to search item in a table

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

modify search

```
<div class="highlight_2"> <a href="#" rel="toggle[inox]" data-openimage="images/collapse2.jpg" data-closedimage="images/expand2.jpg"><img src="images/collapse2.jpg" width="151" height="28" border="0" /></a>
                  <div id="inox">
<input type="checkbox" value="kar_kar" />kar and kar <br />
<input type="checkbox" value="bala_bala" />bala and bala  <br />
<input type="checkbox" value="jena_jena" />jena and jena <br />
<input type="checkbox" value="senapati" />senapati <br />
<input type="checkbox" value="sarangi_sarangi" />sarangi and sarangi <br />
<input type="checkbox" value="sairam" />sairam <br />
<input type="checkbox" value="madhumita" />madhumita <br />
                     <div class="clear"></div>
                  </div>
```

search table

```
 <tr>
<td>Sl No.</td>
<td>Bus Operator</td>
<td>Bus No.    </td>
<td>Departure Time</td>
<td>Arrival time</td>
</tr>
<?php
 $count=0;
$s=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  bus_detail where source_point='$_SESSION[source_point]' && destination_point='$_SESSION[destination]'");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($s))
{
$count+=1;
?>

 <tr>
 <td><?php echo $count; ?></td>
<td><input name="bus_name" type="text" value="<?php echo $row['bus_name'];?>" class="input_box" />  </td>
<td><?php echo $row['bus_no'];?></td>
   <td><?php echo $row['departure_time'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['arrival_time'];?></td>
</tr>
<?php }?>
```

[image]

I want to use my modify search in a ajax oncheck event.. In the picture i ve given ,this is my search list apper but if i check a check box name "jena and jena" from the bus operator div, it should only show me the result of jena and jena , the other two, i want to hide them .. I want to modify my search according to my bus operators(after checking a check box from the operator list).. It ll be a great help .. Thank you

My database :

[image]

Comment: use jQuery on Click event, and on click send ajax request to your scrip which does database work and returns the result

Comment: can you write me the code plzzzz @sravis

Comment: If you require me to do your home work completly, Consider hiring me :-)

Comment: first u help me to get into that position by writing me this code then ofcourse i ll ;) .. But for now, will you please ?? It ll be a  great help ... plz

Comment: hello sarmistha!! can you just post the columns of your table??

Comment: there are 24 columns , but 1st i want to modify my search according to it's bus operators...  @Letmesee

Comment: i ve update my question n added my database @Letmesee

Comment: Pass the checked value through ajax and append the same in the mysql query..

Comment: i want that particular code

Comment: how does the search take place??on checking the checkbox??

Comment: yeah rite.. i want to do my modify search on checking checkbox, somwhow like this http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp .. but my normal search, m doing by simple php queries .. this is what i want to do http://www.redbus.in/Booking/SelectBus.aspx?fromCityId=74676&fromCityName=Bhubaneswar&toCityId=74820&toCityName=Kolkata&doj=14-Dec-2013&busType=Any&opId=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry i miss understood your question. I think you are looking to hide / show html table rows when user selects list. If this is what you are look, Then please check by code below.

Note: You can tweak this code to get better performance and result

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/663Mx/2/

```
$("#inox input[type='checkbox']").live('click', function () {

    // STORE CHECKED VALUED IN ARRAY
    var cv = [];
    $("#inox input[type='checkbox']:checked").each(function () {
        cv.push($(this).val());
    });

    // SHOW / HIDE ROWS BY DEFAULT
    if(cv.length <= 0) {
        $("#mytab tbody").find("tr").show();
    } else {
        $("#mytab tbody").find("tr").hide();

    var rows = $("#mytab tbody").find("tr");
    var data = $(this).val();

    // LOOP THROUGH AND SHOW ONLY CHECKED ROWS
    rows.each(function (i, v) {
        for (var n=0; n<cv.length; n++) {

            var check = $(v).find('td').filter(":contains('" + cv[n] + "')");
            check.parent('tr').show();
        }

    });

   }


});
```

Comment: like this.. but i want to search according to the user checks name from the check box list

Comment: i ve mailed you my problem.. kindly see

Comment: live has been deprecated please use .on('click', func.. instead